# Como faço para usar o Page nessa consulta em vez do List?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-data

```
@Query(value="SELECT * FROM prot_protocolo where status = 'PENDENTE' AND departamento_id=?", nativeQuery=true)
    public List<Protocolo> findByProtocolosPorDepartamento(String id);
```

O page não aceita nativeQuery, da erro quando executo a query, eu tentei assim:

```
public Page<Protocolo> findByProtocolosPorDepartamento(Pageable pageable, String id);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O primeiro ponto é que a informação de paginação na assinatura do método deve ser o último argumento. No seu caso, basta ter algo assim:

```
Page<Protocolo> findByProtocolosPorDepartamento(String id, Pageable pageable);
```

No entanto, conforme descrito [aqui](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#_native_queries), não é possível usar ainda queries nativas ou *sorting* dinâmicos e o spring data "gerar o restante":

> Note, that we currently don’t support execution of dynamic sorting for
>   native queries as we’d have to manipulate the actual query declared
>   and we cannot do this reliably for native SQL

Neste caso você deve implementar a parte de count, seria algo assim:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM prot_protocolo where status = 'PENDENTE' AND departamento_id = :id",
    countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM prot_protocolo where status = 'PENDENTE' AND departamento_id = :id",
    nativeQuery = true)
Page<Protocolo> findByProtocolosPorDepartamento(String id, Pageable pageable);
```

Talvez a "melhor" solução seria você prover um método, usando *property expressions* mesmo, que fará com que o spring data gere o JPQL necessário para a sua consulta, algo como isto:

```
Page<Protocolo> findByStatusAndDepartamento(final String status, final Departamento departamento, final Pageable pageable);
```

Uma última alternativa, caso a paginação não esteja "resolvendo" com queries nativa é você implementar a parte de paginação por sua conta própria usando o suporte do SpEL no spring data, algo parecido com [este exemplo](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/sample/UserRepository.java#L526), mas pode quebrar a independência de bancos de dados.